# Elasticsearch- nested conditional statements

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to develop multiple if else condition like this :

```
if(condition 1)
{
process 1

}
else 
{
   if(condition 2.1)
      { 
            process 2
          }
    else (condition 2.2)
         { process 3
             }

}
```

is bool with must and should the optimized way to do it or can script be used? As my query is already huge, since it has fuzziness and wildcard already.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use painless script query for your use case. Bool must query will not work in this case I think.

You can refer this page for how to use if else in the script query
.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.0/painless-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /books/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "user",
    "privacy"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              { //if
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "user.privacy.mode": {
                          "value": 0
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "privacy.mode": {
                          "value": 0
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {//else if
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "user.privacy.mode": {
                          "value": 2
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "minimum_should_match": 1,
                        "should": [
                          {// if
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "readers",
                              "query": {
                                "match": {
                                  "readers.id": "621120dc86b8920019295363"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          { // else
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "buyers",
                              "query": {
                                "match": {
                                  "buyers.purchase.id": "621120dc86b8920019290f50"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {// else if
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "privacy.mode": {
                          "value": 2
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "minimum_should_match": 1,
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "readers",
                              "query": {
                                "match": {
                                  "readers.id": "621120dc86b89200195373"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "buyers",
                              "query": {
                                "match": {
                                  "buyers.purchase.id": "621120dc86b892001929036350"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user.privacy.mode": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "privacy.mode": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```